# Logging in to site from own form without Webview

Tags: java, android, authentication, http-post

Hi I am trying to figure out how to log on to a site from my own Android form in a app, without using Webview so then when its authenticated I can then parse the HTML content of the next page. All I need is to enter the username the password is not necessary.

The HTML is as follows

```
<form id="ism_login" action="/M/home.mc" method="POST"> 
<fieldset> 
<legend><h2>Login</h2></legend> 
<label>Username</label> 
<input type="text" inputmode="cyrillic predictOff" id="user_name" name="user_name"         size="15" /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="ism_submit" value="Go" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="FPL|is_playing_game_cb" value="1" />
```

here is the test.java

```
package com.test;
public class test extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static EditText edit;
private TextView text;
private String userName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxt);

    Button logIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logIn);
    //Set up listeners
    logIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            userName = edit.getText().toString();


        }
    });


   }//onCreate
 }
```

If you could help me that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use a webview but then attach an overridden [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and override [`shouldOverideUrlLoading`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) to get the URL before it loads in the webview. You can then use that url to do whatever you need to do. Here is an [example](http://schwiz.net/blog/2011/using-scribe-with-android/) using this method to do an oauth sign-on with twitter. I hope this helps!